# Is there a way to hide header title for react-navigation-drawer component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I'm making an app using react navigation-drawer for native, and I was wondering if it is possible to hide just the header title without hiding other things with for example

`headerShown: false`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass an empty string just like this

```
options={() => ({
          headerTitle: "",
 })}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I found the way to do it in options property of drawer screen you can set the `headerTitle` to `''`

```
<Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{title: 'Home', headerTitle:''}}/>
```

the `title` is the name of the Screen shown in the drawer menu, and the `headerTitle` is of course the one shown on the top of the screen, on the header